# Какой оптимальный способ конвертировать дженерик лист в дженерик массив без рефлексии?

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции

Упрощенная версия кода

```
 public V[] values() {
        List<V> values = pojo.getValues();

        return ; // values to array
    }
```

Сигнатура метода требует вернуть V[]. Как перегнать List в V[] без использования рефлексии?
Я не могу использовать values.toArray (new V[0]) или создать и заполнить массив самостоятельно из-за ошибки -  "Type parameter 'V' cannot be instantiated directly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете написать что-то такое. Это не очень красивое решение и IDE будет вам говорит про Unchecked Cast, но работать это будет корректно.

```
public V[] values(List<V> values) {
        Object[] result = new Object[values.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            result[i] = values.get(i);
        }
        return (V[]) result;
    }
```

Comment: спасибо, как раз на этом варианте и остановился. Хочу уточнить, не будет ли у такого варианта решения последствий, которые могут привести ошибкам?

Comment: Ну ошибки тут вряд-ли будут, если только кто-то не влезет в функцию. Раньше то коллекции по такому же принципу и работали пока не появились Generic Type.

Comment: Падает ClassCastException